# refresh specific controller $scope from service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, scope, local-storage

Here's the situation: I have a service that uses **LocalStorage** to save some Objects when I click some buttons.

These LocalStorage Objects are connected to my **Header $scope**.
The problem is that I only load the header (and its $scope) when I load the first page and then it reamins stucked, 'cause there is no need to load it every time I change the page.
But, actually, I need the header to "reload" its $scope when I'm done with saving things in LocalStorage, because in it I have a badge that has to show the updated length of LocalStorage elements (it's a Cart badge, to be clear).

So, is there a way to refresh a specific controller $scope from a Service or from another Controller? Maybe with some $scope.$apply() thing? 
Or there is a way to bind the LocalStorage element in the Header controller in order to do something when it has changed?

PS: No, I can't move out the Cart badge from the header and Yes, I really have to use LocalStorage (it's a specific request).

Comment: Can you post some example code, maybe a plunker?  I'm thinking it might work to use something like $scope.$watch(function(){return myService.getCount()}, function(){$scope.count = myService.getCount()});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to message between your scopes, as angular scopes use [prototype inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). In short if you have a parent scope with a property "foo", and you update "foo" in a child scope, the child scope gets a "new copy" of "foo".

To achieve what you want one can use [`$scope.$emit()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to send an event updates through the scope hierarchy and [`$scope.$on()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) to receive events. Something like this.

```
function ParentController($scope, ...) {

     $scope.numberOfThings = 5;

     // Process 'updateThings' event 
     $scope.$on('updateThings', function(value) { 
         $scope.numberOfThings = value; 
     }); 
}

...

function ChildController($scope, ...) {

     $scope.someCallback = function() {

          // Send 'updateThings' up the scope chain. 
          $scope.$emit('updateThings', 47); 
     }
}
```

If you want to do this the other way around, one can push events downward through the scope chain, one can use [`$scope.$broadcast()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

Comment: Thanks, it really helped.
Using emit() with the button div contoller and on() with rootController in the Header solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` in Header and you can update `$rootScope` value from another controller.

Answer (score 0):

'Refreshing' the controller is usually done **not** directly by using data in `$rootScope`, but by creating and emitting custom events with `$emit` method

You can emit your own event through the `$rootScope` and it will then be propagated to all child scopes, where you can listen on that event

```
////// controller or service or directive

$rootScope.$emit('myOwnEvent', dataObj);

////// another controller

$scope.$on('myOwnEvent', function(newData) {
    $scope.data = newData; // or whatever
});
```